# How to open VNC connection in maximized window using .vnc file

Tags: windows, vnc, tightvnc, window-maximization

I am using TightVNC along with a .vnc file to connect to a remote VNC server.  The connection works, but the TightVNC window that opens is not maximized.  I have searched for .vnc file options to specify window size/maximize but can't find it.  Is there an option I can add to the .vnc file that says "Window Size = Maximized" or similar?

Please note that I do **not** want to go into "Full Screen" mode.  That's a different option.  I simply want the VNC window to be maximized on the desktop.

Thank you for any help.

Update:
After reviewing the TightVNC source code, client-config-lib/ConnectionConfig.cpp, it appears the following are the only supported options in a .vnc file:

```
  bool allowedCopyRect;
  unsigned char preferredEncoding;
  bool use8BitColor;
  int customCompressionLevel;
  int jpegCompressionLevel;
  bool viewOnly;
  bool isClipboardEnabled;
  bool useFullscreen;
  bool deiconifyOnRemoteBell;
  int scaleNumerator;
  int scaleDenominator;
  bool swapMouse;
  bool requestSharedSession;
  bool fitWindow;
  bool requestShapeUpdates;
  bool ignoreShapeUpdates;
  int localCursor;
```

So I don't think this is possible in TightVNC... Can anyone correct me on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to write a simple batch file where you first open the connection using [TightVNC Viewer commands](https://www.tightvnc.com/vncviewer.1.php) and then you maximise the open window with something like:

```
call windowMode -title "TightVNC Viewer" -mode maximized
```

Comment: I need a command to go in the .vnc file.  I tried adding "mode=maximized" to the [options] section but it doesn't work.  What is the comparable command for the .vnc file vs command line option?

Comment: Also, where can I get a complete list of .vnc file configuration options?